# Memory management in python list

Tags: python, memory, memory-leaks, gtk, glade

I'm developing a gtk GUI app to read data from file and plot these data using matplotlib. I'm using python3 and glade.

The main panel of the app take the name of the file and some parameters; with a "plot" button the program calls a handler that begins the data processing.

Now the files i'm processing are big and when plotting the program takes 2 GB of my system's memory. The problem is that when i change the input file for exemple (without closing the main app panel) and click the plot button again, the program doesn't free the 2gb previously used, but add another 2gb on the RAM usage.

I've tried deleting the reference to the list where i store the data from the file, but it didn't work.

Comment: How did you "delete the reference to the list"?

Comment: Python is a language with automatic memory management, objects which are no longer referenced are free to be garbage collected. The CPython implementation uses *reference counting* as its (main) garbage collection strategy. When a reference count reaches 0, the object is *immediately reclaimed*. The most straightforward explanation is that either your list is still referenced somewhere, or the objects contained in the list are still referenced somewhere. Without a [mcve], it's impossible to say anything more specific

Comment: using the command `del`